# Replace sync method with async one

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, async-await

How can I make this method asynchronous?

```
public List<ItemsList> GetAllItems()
        {
            List<ItemsList> items = new List<ItemsList>();
            string query= String.Format("SELECT MFPARTN, MFDSC, sum(QHAVL) as Total FROM IPMFF");
            newConnection.OpenConnection();
            command = new Command(Query, newConnection.ConnectionInstance);
            dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
            ItemsList itemsList = null;
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                itemsList = new ItemsList();

                if (System.DBNull.Value != dataReader["MFPARTN"])
                {
                    itemsList.ItemNumber = (dataReader["MFPARTN"].ToString());
                }
                if (System.DBNull.Value != dataReader["MFDSC"])
                {
                    itemsList.ItemDescription = (dataReader["MFDSC"].ToString());
                }
                if (System.DBNull.Value != dataReader["Total"])
                {
                    itemsList.ItemQuantity = (Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["Total"]));
                }
                items.Add(itemsList);
            }
            return items;
        }
```

Merely putting `async` and `await` does not seem to be working. Also, how can I make it a `Task` method? I am new to async methods, so.

> Update

I have modified the method like this.

```
public Task<List<ItemsList>> GetAllItems()
            {
                List<ItemsList> items = new List<ItemsList>();
                string query= String.Format("SELECT MFPARTN, MFDSC, sum(QHAVL) as Total FROM IPMFF");
                newConnection.OpenConnection();
                command = new Command(Query, newConnection.ConnectionInstance);
                dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                ItemsList itemsList = null;
                while (await dataReader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    itemsList = new ItemsList();

                    if (System.DBNull.Value != dataReader["MFPARTN"])
                    {
                        itemsList.ItemNumber = (dataReader["MFPARTN"].ToString());
                    }
                    if (System.DBNull.Value != dataReader["MFDSC"])
                    {
                        itemsList.ItemDescription = (dataReader["MFDSC"].ToString());
                    }
                    if (System.DBNull.Value != dataReader["Total"])
                    {
                        itemsList.ItemQuantity = (Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["Total"]));
                    }
                    items.Add(itemsList);
                }
                return items;
            }
```

But it is returning this error when I execute this piece of code.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`System.Collections.Generic.List`, but
>   this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`

Comment: That's right. It doesn't. There's a stack trace. But there's no clue of which line caused it.

Comment: I have done that too.

Comment: I doesn't take me to any _line_ in the IDE which caused the issue for me to look it up. The error is still thrown in the browser.

Comment: Your method doesn't return a `Task<T>`.

Comment: Okay. And how do I make it return `Task<T>`?

Comment: ADO.NET has an asynchronous API. What's that `newConnection` and `Command`?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a simple `Task<T>` to handle your `GetAllItems` function like so.

```
public Task<List<ItemsList>> GetListOfItems(){
//Simply pass in your GetAllItems Method
return Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>GetAllItems());
}
```

You can now create a function to handle the asynchronous operation like under:

```
 public async void GetListOfItemsAsync(){
List<ItemsList> myItems=await GetListOfItems();
//Do something with your list...
}
```

There are other ways to do this. I would suggest you read up Microsoft's documentation on [Asynchronous programming with async and await (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

Comment: Where did this `return Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>GetAllItems());` come from?

Comment: This `GetAllItems()`?

Comment: `GetAllItems()` is the name of your synchronous method.

Comment: Note that you need the namespaces `using System.Threading.Tasks;` and 
`using System.Threading;`.

Comment: Where did you see mixing `Task.Factory.StartNew(` with `async-await` as a good practice?